# HttpClient throwing error in Angular when used in service

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `HttpClient` in angular 6 in my service as follows:

**auth.service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public dataService: DataService, private config: AppConfig) {
        console.log(this.config);
    }
```

This `http:HttpClient` is the reason I am getting the following error. When I remove this, the error goes. I am not sure why this error is coming.

```
core.js:1521 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at http.js:108
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:102)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:166)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:235)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1445)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
```

Comment: Can you add your TS Import line ?

Comment: Do you mean the service import? I am declaring it in providers in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Your TS import. It's to be sure you don't have `import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';`

Comment: No, it is this one - `import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";`

Comment: And you don't have to put it in your provider but you have to use `HttpClientModule`

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete code of auth.service.ts?

Answer (score 1):

In Your `app.module.ts`:

import `HttpClientModule,` under imports array:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
   imports: [ ..., HttpClientModule, ...]  // import here
```

And now you can inject HttpClient in your service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 ...............
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, public dataService: DataService, private 
 config: AppConfig) {
       console.log(this.config);
  }
```

Make sure your service is `Injectable` and provided in 'root' or in the AppModule providers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually `HttpClient`.

You call

```
console.log(this.config);
```

in the constructor, but pass config *as a parameter to* `constructor()`.

Passing parameters to the `constructor()` doesn't automatically set their similarly-named `this.` counterpart.

You probably want

```
console.dir(config);
```

or

```
this.config = config;
console.dir(this.config);
```

(Also, use `console.dir()` for objects.)

Comment: Thanks. But even after removing this console.log statement, I am getting the same error. I think it has something to do with httpClient as I am getting error in `http.js`

Comment: @Coder You're causing an exception to be thrown in the constructor, so other things later will likely fail. Is there more code in the service, or just that? If so please update the question.

Comment: When the parameter in the constructor is declared as `public` or `private` it is added to `this.` and is it also accessible directly. Without the `public` or `private` it works as you are saying.